# Exception Handling "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: swing, jdbc

I am getting the following error in my program:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:730)
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:473)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.elementAt(DefaultListModel.java:266)
    at bfpl.BFPL$1$2$13.actionPerformed(BFPL.java:851)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

AND MY CODE IS:

```
final JFrame f8=new JFrame("New Schedule");
                                    f8.setVisible(true);
                                    f3.setVisible(false);
                                    f8.setSize(1000,1000);
                                    f8.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                    final JPanel p8=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                                    GridBagConstraints g8=new GridBagConstraints();
                                    g8.insets=new Insets(2,2,2,2);
                                    JButton b21=new JButton("Back");
                                    JButton b22=new JButton("Save");
                                    JLabel l40=new JLabel("Match No");
                                    JLabel l41=new JLabel("Home Team");
                                    JLabel l42=new JLabel("Away Team");
                                    JLabel l43=new JLabel("Stadium");
                                    JLabel l44=new JLabel("Date");
                                    JLabel l45=new JLabel("mm/dd/yyyy");
                                    JLabel l56=new JLabel("City");
                                    final JTextField t38=new JTextField(15);
                                    JTextField t39=new JTextField(15);
                                    DefaultListModel dl1=new DefaultListModel();
                                    DefaultListModel dl2=new DefaultListModel();
                                    DefaultListModel dl3=new DefaultListModel();
                                    DefaultListModel dl9=new DefaultListModel();
                                    String query1="Select Stadium,Location from Stadiums";
                                    try{
                                        try {
                                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                                            Logger.getLogger(BFPL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                        }
                                        Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/BFPL","root","ilovepepsi");
                                        Statement stm=(Statement) con1.createStatement();
                                        ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(query1);
                                        while(rs.next()){
                                            String std=rs.getString("Stadium");
                                            String std1=rs.getString("Location");
                                            dl1.addElement(std);
                                            dl9.addElement(std1);
                                        }

                                    }   
                                    catch(SQLException ae){
                                        System.out.println("SQLException:"+ae.getMessage());
                                        System.out.println("SQLState:"+ae.getSQLState());
                                        System.out.println("VendorError:"+ae.getErrorCode());
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p8,"Error in submitting data!");
                                    }
                                    String query2="Select Team_Name from Team";
                                    try{
                                        Connection con2=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/BFPL","root","ilovepepsi");
                                        Statement stm1=con2.createStatement();
                                        ResultSet rs1=stm1.executeQuery(query2);
                                        while(rs1.next()){
                                            String t=rs1.getString("Team_Name");
                                            dl2.addElement(t);
                                            dl3.addElement(t);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch(SQLException ae){
                                        System.out.println("SQLException:"+ae.getMessage());
                                        System.out.println("SQLState:"+ae.getSQLState());
                                        System.out.println("VendorError:"+ae.getErrorCode());
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p8,"Error in submitting data!");
                                    }
                                    JList li1=new JList(dl1);
                                    JList li2=new JList(dl2);
                                    JList li3=new JList(dl3);
                                    JList li9=new JList(dl9);
                                    li1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                                    li1.setVisibleRowCount(2);
                                    li2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                                    li2.setVisibleRowCount(2);
                                    li3.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                                    li3.setVisibleRowCount(2);
                                    li9.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                                    li9.setVisibleRowCount(2);
                                    f8.add(p8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=0;
                                    p8.add(l40,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=0;
                                    p8.add(t38,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=1;
                                    p8.add(l41,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=1;
                                    p8.add(new JScrollPane(li3),g8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=2;
                                    p8.add(l42,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=2;
                                    p8.add(new JScrollPane(li2),g8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=3;
                                    p8.add(l43,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=3;
                                    p8.add(new JScrollPane(li1),g8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=4;
                                    p8.add(l56,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=4;
                                    p8.add(new JScrollPane(li9),g8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=5;
                                    p8.add(l44,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=5;
                                    p8.add(t39,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=2;
                                    g8.gridy=5;
                                    p8.add(l45,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=0;
                                    g8.gridy=6;
                                    p8.add(b21,g8);
                                    g8.gridx=1;
                                    g8.gridy=6;
                                    p8.add(b22,g8);

                                    int a1=li1.getSelectedIndex();
                                    int a2=li2.getSelectedIndex();
                                    int a3=li3.getSelectedIndex();
                                    int a10=li9.getSelectedIndex();
                                    final String st1=(String) dl1.elementAt(a1);
                                    final String st2=(String) dl2.elementAt(a2);
                                    final String st3=(String) dl3.elementAt(a3);
                                    final String st10=(String)dl9.elementAt(a10);
```

Comment: 1) Improve the formatting of the stacktrace 2) Improve the formatting of your code 3) Post the relevant code (see stacktrace to dertermine what is relevant) 4) Remove all the irrelevant code (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Answer (score 0):

So what is at BFPL.java line 851?  That's your problem.  Check the size of the vector before you call Vector#elementAt(n).